# POCO with Generic Type and EF

Tags: entity-framework, generics, types, poco

Is it possible to to use a POCO with generic type and map to Entity Framework Code First?  The reason I ask is I get the following error on the context.Products.Add(product); line of the CreateNewProduct() method -

The type 'CodeFirstNewDBConsole.Product`1[CodeFirstNewDBConsole.ProductDetail]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

POCO

```
public class Product<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public T ProductDetails { get; set; }
}
```

ProductContext

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product<ProductDetail>> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Product insert

```
private static void CreateNewProduct()
    {
        var productDetail = new ProductDetail { ProductDetailName = "Test Product Detail" };

        var product = new Product<ProductDetail>
        {
            ProductName = "Test Product",
            ProductDetails = productDetail
        };

        using (var context = new ProductContext())
        {
            context.Products.Add(product);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic Classes are not supported by Entity Framework. Which is clear from the error message :
"... Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or **generic**, and does not inherit from EntityObject."